# new line character(enter key) in C++

Tags: c++, cin

I want to write a program to do a process after each sentences.
like this:

```
char letter;
while(std::cin >> letter)
{
  if(letter == '\n')
  { 
    // here do the process and show the results.
  }

}
```

I want that when the user press the enter key (means that the sentences is finished)
so that we do a process and then after showing some result the user can enter new phrases but the line
if(letter == '\n')
doesn't work as I expect.
please tell me how I can do this.
thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question and you want to trap the `'\n'` character, then you need to use `std::cin.get(letter)` instead of `std::cin >> letter;` As explained in the comment, the `>>` operator will discard leading whitespace, so the `'\n'` left in `stdin` is ignored on your next loop iteration.

`std::cin.get()` is a raw read and will read each character in `stdin`. See [std::basic_istream::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    
    char letter;
    
    while (std::cin.get(letter)) {
        if (letter == '\n')
            std::cout << "got newline\n";
    }
}
```

Will generate a `"got newline"` output after <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed each time.

Comment: Thank you, I used cin.get() and getline() and both are doing exactly what I want.

Comment: The key is that. If you need to buffer more than one character and operate on a collection of characters, then `std::string` and `getline()` as @silverfox shows would be the way to go. If you are only processing a single character, then `std::cin.get()` will provide a simpler approach. It all depends on what your program needs are.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) probably, because [`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) will stop at whitespaces:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string x;
    while(x != "stop") //something to stop
    {
        std::cout << "Your input : ";
        std::getline(std::cin, x);
        std::cout << "Output : " << x << "\n"; //Do other stuff here, probably
    }
    std::cout << "Stopped";
}
```

Result:

```
Your input : test1
Output : test1
Your input : abc def ghi
Output : abc def ghi
Your input : stop
Output : stop
Stopped
```